# Invalid image file when adding install.wim to wds image

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2, pxe

When trying to add the install.wim file from the Windows 10 iso to WDS install image, I get a error message. "Invalid Image file - The file does not contain a valid install image".

The iso is downloaded from Microsofts official "Media creation tool".
I have tried both home and pro edition

I use Windows server 2008 R2

And thoughts what the fault is?

Comment: Try copying the WIM to a network share and add it from there - it may just not like reading the Wim from ISO (http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/497-windows-deployment-services-add-image-wizard-error/). Also, are you selecting an index to deploy - don't forget that (like Windows 7 and 8) you need to select the version to deploy (Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate etc) as they'll all be in one WIM...

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help, but it didn't work. Tried with both windows share and samba share. The ISO I am using only has one version of windows. I can add the boot.wim to a boot image.

Comment: Does your user account have permissions to write to the WDS share?

Comment: Yes, the account have full permissions. I can add older windows image files. Can windows server 2008 be to old? Or might i need some updates?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be too old because it's just an image storage location (with a few bells and whistles)...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Server 2008 cannot deploy Windows 8 or higher. However, I got the same error trying to add a Windows 10 ISO from the media creation tool to WDS in Server 2012. I talked to my manager and got the Windows 10 Pro volume license ISO. That one added to it just fine.

Comment: I have windows 8 and 8.1 from before. But it sounds like I need another version of the Windows 10 iso. Will try it next week. Thanks!